# Xtick Label Shift Problem with 2 Plots Overlaid

Tags: python, seaborn, axis-labels, xticks

I am trying to make a combined plot using seaborn boxplot and scatterplot. The problem is that my xtick labels are not aligned and I've tried many solutions. the red data values are the values that are not aligned with the boxplot xtcick labels and correspond to the LAST row in the df_concat df shown below. The truncated boxplot data is this: df_concat.iloc[:-5,:]. I'll show you my data and then my - incorrect plot.

df_concat:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0   704.8   785.4   743.2   945.2   650.5   775.8   841.8   561.2   548.5   690.2   785.8   822.5
1   833.8   827.0   734.7   819.1   668.4   612.5   745.4   472.1   368.6   644.8   893.0   652.5
2   776.6   762.1   825.0   873.5   954.3   705.4   612.1   388.8   444.8   660.5   786.5   693.3
3   942.0   914.3   862.8   928.7   1136.5  645.8   638.2   552.3   514.7   736.5   850.9   851.9
4   829.1   738.3   733.4   823.4   599.0   635.3   603.4   586.0   419.5   662.2   732.7   818.5
5   845.7   798.6   924.4   762.7   831.8   1033.7  626.9   426.1   461.8   725.9   713.2   763.7
6   932.7   885.9   880.1   1028.0  855.3   758.8   573.9   476.8   455.4   537.7   574.1   800.5
7   827.6   932.2   898.1   871.2   939.7   836.2   631.6   455.7   548.4   710.1   803.6   790.8
8   777.7   839.3   680.6   995.1   807.1   656.2   592.8   536.2   474.6   694.2   678.0   768.1
9   891.6   772.7   932.5   961.0   947.1   633.9   617.6   551.8   547.1   548.4   714.6   857.6
10  685.5   828.3   669.1   890.0   795.0   611.8   536.2   447.2   471.4   529.9   807.5   818.6
11  751.7   760.7   780.8   823.1   874.8   693.2   532.2   543.7   411.6   747.7   744.8   774.1
12  784.8   686.4   787.8   876.3   713.4   726.0   537.1   485.5   475.1   547.5   764.2   784.8
13  854.9   858.4   1009.9  930.2   757.3   552.8   479.1   532.3   529.3   648.0   759.9   780.7
14  749.1   763.7   842.9   825.6   674.0   634.3   443.8   420.0   402.2   586.4   664.3   886.0
15  924.9   938.0   1016.6  957.2   914.8   848.2   539.3   434.9   447.4   569.3   681.2   923.6
16  816.9   990.5   958.6   994.2   763.1   742.7   714.1   593.5   425.7   814.2   599.2   745.2
17  798.4   696.2   843.6   898.5   880.9   758.0   555.7   459.3   509.2   586.3   885.1   834.6
18  742.0   978.1   912.6   1173.1  1081.3  831.5   596.2   536.1   476.1   638.7   926.8   798.6
19  835.7   777.0   909.1   848.8   775.0   634.2   585.0   564.0   518.9   724.7   657.8   848.7
20  815.2   825.9   886.9   906.8   899.3   715.2   540.5   472.0   519.7   664.4   752.5   744.3
21  843.2   818.8   830.9   910.5   880.5   887.3   562.8   555.5   490.4   567.0   843.8   695.8
22  706.6   740.0   550.6   726.7   869.0   514.6   690.1   490.0   441.0   590.3   785.0   848.6
23  772.8   810.4   835.3   730.8   720.3   490.0   748.9   505.5   462.7   545.0   654.9   825.2
24  923.1   902.4   874.9   911.3   844.3   609.6   554.7   616.5   558.8   631.4   735.5   721.2
25  780.9   875.5   854.5   884.1   805.4   803.7   552.6   610.1   421.7   694.2   730.5   823.8
26  787.4   787.8   824.8   861.4   919.0   693.1   652.8   627.4   555.2   756.1   750.3   744.5
27  857.4   856.0   943.0   796.8   824.3   688.4   664.2   460.9   588.9   658.2   657.9   806.5
28  783.4   910.7   866.2   850.2   798.1   621.5   446.9   518.8   504.1   626.2   662.4   894.6
29  769.9   792.2   820.6   1027.8  1007.9  706.0   677.0   539.4   349.1   569.3   779.7   778.4
30  276.9   415.7   435.1   538.7   561.7   583.4   580.5   503.8   364.2   353.4   320.0   245.1
31  292.6   220.4   259.4   171.4   188.3   196.0   175.2   146.9   233.5   280.3   305.3   270.4
32  280.9   241.2   280.6   263.2   204.7   164.7   120.1   111.2   144.8   225.9   264.0   267.2
33  322.9   267.5   324.9   301.3   274.2   249.1   195.2   188.8   252.7   300.9   329.5   321.0
34  545.3   496.3   533.2   450.0   492.8   394.6   362.0   330.6   289.4   367.8   423.5   528.5
```

Here is the bad plot as a result of the code shown below.

[image]

Here is my faulty code:

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# make the boxplot of data for rows 1-29 only
df_concat = df_concat.reset_index(drop=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
g = sns.boxplot(data=df_concat.iloc[:-5,:],
            orient='v', color='y',whis=100)
g.set_xticks(range(0,12))
g.set_xticklabels(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'])
#add scatterplot BUDGET data...using only last row in df_concat
g = sns.scatterplot(x=df_concat.iloc[-1,:].index,
                y=df_concat.iloc[-1,:], color='red',marker='o',label='2023 Budget')
g.set_xticklabels(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/faq#why-can-t-i-draw-a-line-over-a-bar-box-strip-violin-plot

Comment: In your case, the easiest option is to convert the column names to strings `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)` then scatterplot and boxplot xticks index will match. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J17i0.png). Otherwise, you can leave the labels as numbers and use `sns.stripplot(x=df.iloc[-1,:].index, y=df.iloc[-1,:], color='red',marker='o', ax=g)`, but it's a categorical plot, like boxplot.